# How do I change the background color of UIScrollView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am running Xcode 11 and would like to be able to change the background color of a UIScrollView as it moves from page to page in a 6 page setup. I have been able to change the label content for each page but the background color 'skips' to the last in the color array.

The arrays:

```
let stringArray = ["<- Swipe to begin", "Welcome", "Info", "more info", "more info 2", "end"]

let backgroundColorArray = [UIColor.orange, UIColor.blue, UIColor.red, UIColor.white, UIColor.green, UIColor.purple]
```

Then the scrollview content

```
func setupScrollView() {
    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width * 6, height: scrollView.frame.size.height)

    for k in 0 ... 5 {
        scrollView.backgroundColor = backgroundColorArray[k]
    }

    for i in 0 ... 5 {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: scrollView.center.x + CGFloat(i) * self.view.frame.size.width - 130, y: 50, width: 260, height: 30))
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 26)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = stringArray[i]

        scrollView.addSubview(label)
    }
}
```

The scrollview background color changes to purple but does not change from page to page. What is the correct way to have the colors change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are calling

```swift
for k in 0 ... 5 {
    scrollView.backgroundColor = backgroundColorArray[k]
}
```

you are looping through each color in `backgroundColorArray` and updating the value. Because `.purple` is the last element in your `backgroundColorArray`, your scroll view, at the end of this for loop, is being set to purple. Your for loop is essentially doing the same thing as `scrollView.backgroundColor = backgroundColorArray[5]`.

Now, what I suggest you do is implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods. You could implement `scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView:)`. This is called every time the scroll view's content offset changes. What you could then do is set a switch statement that checks the content offset of your scroll view, and assigns the color accordingly:

```swift
extension MyViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        //Assuming your pages are situated horizontally from one another
        let page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / view.frame.width
        if page < 1 {
            scrollView.backgroundColor = backgroundColorArray[0]
        } else if page > 1 && page < 2 {
            scrollView.backgroundColor = backgroundColorArray[1]
        } else if page > 2 && page < 3 {
            scrollView.backgroundColor = backgroundColorArray[2]
        } else if page > 3 && page < 4 {
            scrollView.backgroundColor = backgroundColorArray[3]
        } else if page > 4 && page < 5 {
            scrollView.backgroundColor = backgroundColorArray[4]
        } else if page > 5 && page < 6 {
            scrollView.backgroundColor = backgroundColorArray[5]
        }
    }
}
```

You could also [interpolate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868182/uicolor-transition-based-on-progress-value) between colors depending on your scroll view's content offset. Here is a `UIColor` extension I use to do this:

```swift
extension UIColor {
    static func interpolate(from fromColor: UIColor, to toColor: UIColor, with progress: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
        let fromComponents = fromColor.components
        let toComponents = toColor.components

        let r = (1 - progress) * fromComponents.r + progress * toComponents.r
        let g = (1 - progress) * fromComponents.g + progress * toComponents.g
        let b = (1 - progress) * fromComponents.b + progress * toComponents.b
        let a = (1 - progress) * fromComponents.a + progress * toComponents.a

        return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    }
}
```

**However** I highly suggest you take a look at [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller). It sounds like it does more of what you are trying to manually do yourself. Check out this question I asked recently: [Pan (not swipe) between view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57504675/pan-not-swipe-between-view-controllers)

Comment: I actually started with PageView but it doesn't work for this project because I am integrating Lottie. The above code never gets called, so I can't really tell if it is working or not.

Comment: Sorry, try replacing `scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView!)` with `scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)`. Assuming you've set your scroll view's delegate to your view controller (which it seems you have) and extended your view controller as a UIScrollViewDelegate and implemented this delegate method, it should be called every time the scroll view "scrolls".

Comment: That made the difference. Thank you.

Comment: Not a problem. Do you mind DMing me at some point why Lottie doesn't work with UIPageViewController? I just made a tinder-like application that utilizes a side-scrolling UIPageViewController, and feel I may be able to help. Or at least share some useful code.

Comment: Be happy to. I'll connect on LinkedIn.